# TikZ: Add decoration on a smooth coordinates plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I would like to draw a smooth curve that I get from a coordinate plot after adding some additional decorations. So far I have.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [blue] plot [smooth] coordinates { (0.2,0.2) (0.4,0.2) (0.6,0.22) (0.8,0.52) (1,0.22) (1.2,0.2) (1.4,0.2)} [postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={random steps, segment length = 0.4mm, amplitude = 0.5pt}}] (0.2,0.2) -- (1.4,0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This code however plots both the smooth line with the decoration and a line from `(0.2,0.2)` to `(1.4,0.2)`

[image: Result]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: You should post a picture of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @jubobs He can't (not enough reputation), but he can provide a link to the image (uploaded to some pastebin) and I can insert it in the question.

Comment: @Jubobs You can find some nice alternatives for such greeting comments in here http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks

Comment: @Percusse Sorry, I'm relatively new to tex.stackexchange. Will do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `--` between the start and the end of the path. `--` tells explicitly TikZ to draw a line between 2 points ...

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [blue] plot [smooth] coordinates { (0.2,0.2) (0.4,0.2) (0.6,0.22) (0.8,0.52) (1,0.22) (1.2,0.2) (1.4,0.2)} [postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={random steps, segment length = 0.4mm, amplitude = 0.5pt}}] (0.2,0.2)  (1.4,0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

There seems to be a conflict between the `smooth` option and the `postaction` key, issuing several "Dimension too large", that *can*  be ignored...

**Edit2: about closed path**

The smoothing of the curves needs to compute other utility points. When the path is closed, you can consider that you do not have a beginning and an ending: all points of the path have a predecessor and a successor.

When the path is opened, the point in the beginning does not have a predecessor, and TikZ seem here to use a *predecessor* equal to this point, resulting a segment of zero width. But this segment is treated by your postaction decoration, issuing an error of calculation, with no incidence on the result.

[image: difference between open and closed path]

Comment: I get an "Dimension too large" error. Could you post the complete code?

Comment: I'll check this; I'm using TexMaker that doesn't display these errors...

Comment: @Jubobs Very strange... With `--` it compiles fine, removing `--` should not do issue such an error...

Comment: @LionelMANSUY In any case, what is the difference between removing `--` or removing the final part of the path, i.e. `(0.2,0.2) -- (1.4,0.2)` altogheter? If you remove the `--`, but leave the coordinates, you only cause the "plotting pen" to move without drawing. You can remove the coordinates too and get the same result. In fact, you'll get the same `Dimension too large` error :-(

Comment: @JLDiaz No difference. Also you can shift the postaction options to the beginning as there is no difference in placement anyway. Or draw it directly.

Comment: @JLDiaz you're right; is that a bug in TikZ?

Comment: @LionelMANSUY Not sure.. the conflict is between the `[smooth]` option and pathmorphing decoration (it also crashes with `bumps`, `snake` and `zigzag`). Perhaps in the internal computations made to decorate the curve some tex register was overful.

Comment: @JLDiaz The `smooth` option (with an open curve) uses control points with null distance at each extremity: it's a pity!

Comment: @PaulGaborit That explains why if you close the curve the problem disappears, thanks!

Comment: I think you could add decoration={pre length=0.5cm, post length=0.5cm}, then the errors should go away, but the ends won`t be decorated.